# External reference string in Excel becomes formula only after removing ' from the beginning, why and how to repeat this hundreds of times?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference

I have a couple of hundred workbooks with values in same cells I need to reference to in a Total workbook. So let's say, I need to get the cell value of B1 of each of these books (each workbook and worksheet is built exactly the same - the workbooks are not saved locally and will be closed most of the time, so Indirect and Power Query don't work). I have the path combined from two parts and the name of the file in one cell, e.g. like this (first part of the function the part of the path that's same to every file, then specific folder, then file name and finally cell reference that's same every time:

="='\company\supervisors\resourcing 2021"&I2&"["&K2&"]Sheet1'!B1", where

Cell I2 has the specific folder and K2 the name of the file. I'll copy and paste the resulting string as value to another cell, after which I'll get something along these lines in this new cell:

'='\company\supervisors\resourcing 2021\resourcing East\East Medium\ [Resourcing Rockhill 2021.xlsm]Sheet1'!B1 (note that there's actually no space after "Medium" , but for some reason the \ sign disappeared after this question was formatted if I didn't put space there)

However, this is simply a string of text, not a formula. if I remove the first ' sign, the string becomes formula that works perfectly. If I try to choose all rows with this "formula" and try to find and replace "'=" with "=", Excel tells me there's nothing to replace. So on some level the first ' sign cannot be found, but if I go into the cell manually and erase it, the formula starts working. Why is this, and how can I do this for each rows without having to do it manually? I don't understand why the first ' sign even exists as I don't have it in the formula - the string in my first formula begins with "=".

I think this could be done with VBA quite easily, but it bothers me since I vividly remember using this homespun "write formula - paste it - find and replace (something?) - ta-dah you have a working external references x 500 now!" approach before and can't remember how I did it. It's annoying me to no end.

Comment: You can replace the file name in the formula manually with search/replace (click Options, then select Look in: Formulas). Much faster with VBA Range.Replace.

Comment: What do you mean? I did try the basic find and replace where I had look in fomulas selected, and tried to replace "'=" with simply "="-

Comment: Excel is converting your formula to a string when you paste it into the cell body. This is the equivalent of setting the **Cell.Value** property in VBA. If you want to update the cell formula, you can select one or more cells in the worksheet and then paste the formula into the formula bar. This is the equivalent of setting the **Range.Formula** property in VBA.